# MKMap annotation selection

Tags: ios4, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to check when he user presses the annotation (the bubble on top of the pin). I tried the following :

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{}
```

but it fires up when i press the pin. How can i check when the user actually presses on the annotation bubble?

Comment: What do you mean with "the bubble on the top of the pin"? You want to check when user presses the callout bubble or the just the pin?

Answer (score 1):

You can first put a right accessory button and set an separate action for it as such:

```
            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self
                        action:@selector(showDetails:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
```

you can implement the `showDetails` method with the function that you like